# Compiler can't find the file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I just downloaded VScode, installed MingW with all the compilers, debuggers, installed the C/C++ extension for VScode and my C++ program just wouldn't work.

[image: Here's the source code:]
[image: Here's the pop up:]
[image: Here's the dialog of the Terminal:]

I tried reinstall MingW with all its stuffs, changing the extension in VScode but the thing just didn't work. I expected it to print out "hello"

Comment: You can either remove the spaces from your directory name or add quotes to your build command.  `g++` assumes that spaces separate command-line parameters.

Comment: @DrewDormann oh i tried created another c++ file outside the directory and that actually worked thank you. A quick question tho: the directory is the administrator user directory whose name can't be renamed or the system just wouldn't let me. Is there a way for me to change it into something without space? I obviously wanna work inside this dir.

Comment: You could create your folder where you have code in a different location on your hard drive that is not inside the user folder.